# Replicar una tabla cada vez que se actualiza otra

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, if

Tengo dos tablas. `Tabla A` y `Tabla B` y necesito que apenas inserte algo en `Tabla A` se copie de forma idéntica en la `Tabla B`.

Los campos en ambas tablas son: `id`, `nombre` y `posicion`

Ejemplo:

```
Tabla A

id  nombre  posicion
1   carlos     1
2   luis       2
```

A partir de PHP, necesito preguntar si existe algún dato nuevo en `Tabla A` que se necesite copiar en `Tabla B`, y hacerlo obviamente.

Comment: Eso se puede hacer con un trigger, échale un ojo a la documentación, e inténtalo, si te sale una duda más concreta será más fácil ayudarte ya con algo de código
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Estas utilizando pasos de más, sí la tabla se encuentra en la misma bd puedes hacerlo con triggers. sí la tabla B está en otro servidor ouedes internarlo con tablas federadas (aunque es mas dificil que eso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un trigger en tu base de datos para que por cada INSERT en la tablaA tome los datos insertados y los inserte en tablaB:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE
    TRIGGER insert_into_tablaA AFTER INSERT ON tablaA
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tablaB (nombre, posicion) VALUES (new.nombre, new.posicion)
END#;
```