# ¿Como puedo hacer que se guarden datos de una tabla en otra después de actualizarla?

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo una aplicación WEB en **NETBEANS** Y base de datos de **ORACLE** 
lo quisiera es que al momento de actualizar mi formulario, se guarden los datos en otra tabla automáticamente y no solo en su Tabla original.

en mi tabla 1 llamada "tareas" que actualiza tengo.

proceso 1 = 100
proceso 2 = 50
proceso 3 = 20

lo que quiero es que al actualizar sus valores a (por ejemplo)

proceso 1 = 100
proceso 2 = 100
proceso 3 = 100

se actualice en su tabla "Tareas" y en la otra tabla que tengo llamada "respaldo"

les menciono que mi aplicación sirve perfectamente, puedo actualizar y puedo visualizar los datos actualizados en mi base de datos, mi unico problema es que quiero guardarlo en otra tabla.

Muchas gracias anticipadas!

Comment: Les pongo mi codigo de mi actualizacion por que no me dejo agregarlo en la pregunta .

<%
      consulta  conexion = new consulta("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","pasaportes","oppasaportes");
        String query="UPDATE tareas SET proceso1='"+proceso1+"' , proceso2='"+proceso2+"' , proceso3 ='"+proceso3+"' WHERE id_delegacion = '"+ID_DELEGACION+"'";
        int c=conexion.ejeSentencia(query);

        if(c==1){    
   
   
       
       %>

Comment: Si quieres programar la lógica en BD busca sobre Disparadores/Triggers esos te ayudarán con tu problemática.

Comment: Ya leí sobre triggers pero nunca he trabajado con ellos, ¿me podrías ayudar a generar uno?

Comment: no necesariamente necesitas triggers (aunque puede ser una buena idea). Que te impide actualizar todas las tablas manualmente?

Comment: Mira en este post está el código https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62515/replicar-una-tabla-cada-vez-que-se-actualiza-otra/62517#62517 pero esto es para mysql, entonces tienes que revisar la sintaxis para Oracle, y cambiar el nombre de las tablas y columnas para que se adecuen a tu proyecto.

Comment: Como ya te mencionan puedes usar lanzadores para replicar tus tables o hacerlo manual. Cuando llames a tu Dao de Tareas, antes de terminar el método, llama el o los updates que replicaran a otras tablas ... updateRespaldo(Objeto) ...